# opengl camera with z axis

Tags: c++, opengl, camera

How do i create a camera with a rotation on the z axis that can move in every direction? I have tried many things, this is my code:

```
glm::mat4 view = glm::mat4(1.0f);



glm::vec3 camRotInRadians = glm::vec3(toRadians(rot.x), toRadians(rot.y), toRadians(rot.z));



glm::vec3 direction = glm::vec3(
    cos(camRotInRadians.x) * cos(camRotInRadians.y),
    sin(camRotInRadians.x),
    cos(camRotInRadians.x) * sin(camRotInRadians.y)
);

// Right vector
glm::vec3 right = glm::vec3(
    cos(toRadians(rot.z)) * cos(toRadians(rot.y + 270.0f)),
    sin(toRadians(rot.z)),
    cos(toRadians(rot.z)) * sin(toRadians(rot.y + 270.0f))
);

glm::vec3 up = glm::cross(right, direction);

view = glm::lookAt(
    pos - direction * glm::vec3(40.0f),          
    pos + direction, 
    up
);
```

Comment: i must say i don't understand what your problem is, could you elaborate? you get a "rotation on the z axis" by changing the up vector but you seem to do that already. also, what's the problem about "moving in every direction"?

Comment: It also looks like you're using yaw and pitch formulas for your direction vector